# Calculation of work done by a hollow ring on a block that is placed inside it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

In my Work Power Energy textbook(a.k.a module) there is a question I have tried solving but I am unable to solve it. It read like this:

> A block of mass 200 grams is moving with a speed 4 m/s at the highest point in a closed circular tube. of radius 10 cm. The tube is kept in a vertical plane. The cross section of the tube is such that the block just fits in it. If the block makes several oscillations and finally stops at the lowest point of the tube find the work done by the tube on the block. $ g = 10 m/s^2 $

I have tried but am unable to solve it and would be grateful for any help

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start at $t=0$ at the top of the tube. Let's also posit that for each *full* revolution $\frac{W}{n}$ friction work is done on the block.

When it's at its lowest point, after half a revolution, it's total energy is:

$$T=K_0+2mgR-\frac{W}{2n}$$

Then it climbs back up and total energy is:

$$T'=K_0+2mgR-\frac{W}{2n}-2mgR-\frac{W}{2n}=K_0-\frac{W}{n}$$

After $n+\frac12$ revolutions (back at the bottom):

$$0=K_0+2mgR-(n+\frac12)\frac{W}{n}$$

With $K_0=\frac12 mv_0^2$.

Comment: Ok. Will edit now.

Comment: So I was wrong initially: the number of revolutions does matter because there's one last *half revolution*.

Comment: This is simply wrong. $W$ introduction is erroneous. The correct answer is given by Chester Miller.

Comment: @Emil: there was a silly sign *typo*, which I've now corrected. Other than that, my answer is the same as Chester Miller's but with formulas.

Comment: You have formulas, but you don't even have [some quantity] (which should be net work by tube on body) = [some equation]. Work will change with every revolution, it's obvious. You cannot put it to artificial quantity like $W$. Finally, at some point energy will be too small to cross the highest point of a tube again, so movement will become osciallations about the lowest point. Answer is simply $E=\frac{mv^2}{2}+2mgR$.

Comment: The problem specifies: *"If the block makes several oscillations and finally stops at the lowest point of the tube"*. Hence the need to need to introduce $n$. I initially formulated an answer like yours but on closer investigation that doesn't work.

Comment: No need! Problem doesn't even mention the value of $n$, it's just description of physical situation. The tube is the only agent that dissipates total energy of the body, so all its work is equal to the energy of the body. Period.

Answer (score 2):

The mass loses kinetic energy and potential energy due to friction (with the tube).  The amount of kinetic energy and potential energy lost is equal to the work done by friction on the block.